# Unnecessary Fluff

Tags: code-golf, number, array, primes, fibonacci

Following the great advice (what do you mean *it's not advice*?!) on [Adding unnecessary fluff](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384) we can devise the following task:

- Take a list of positive integers and a positive integer \$m\$ as input.
- Only keep the prime values from the list.
- Define \$f(n) = F_{n^2 + 1}\$ (the \$n^2+1\$-th element in the Fibonacci sequence, starting from \$F_0=0, F_1=1\$), \$g(n) = \underbrace{f(f(\cdots f(n)\cdots))}_{m\text{ applications of }f}\$, and \$h(n) = \begin{cases}h(g(n) \mod n) + 1&n\neq0\\0&n=0\end{cases}\$.
- Apply \$h\$ to each element on the list.
- Return the median (you can assume the input contained an odd number of primes).

### Test cases

```
[2,7,11,10,14,4,9], 1 -> 2
[2,7,11,5,13,10,14,4,9], 1 -> 2
[5,5,11,5,13,93,94,95,9], 1 -> 3
[5,7,11], 2 -> 2
[5,5,11], 2 -> 1
[5,43,67], 2 -> 3
[5,43,67], 2 -> 3
[977], 2 -> 5
[719, 727, 733, 739, 743], 2 -> 4
[967], 10 -> 4
[977], 10 -> 3
[5], 10 -> 1
```

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden. You can use any reasonable I/O format.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: How are you defining Fibonacci?

Comment: @Tbw I'm using \$F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1, F_{n+2} = F_n + F_{n+1}\$, but I just noticed that my code doesn't do that - let me fix the test cases.

Comment: Exactly how big is \$g(3)\$? My language reaches its limit at 2.

Comment: @Tbw What do you mean? It depends on \$m\$. \$f(100)\$, or \$f(f(3))\$ should fit in the memory, but not much after that - to compute larger values you can use modular arithmetic to directly compute \$g(n)\mod n\$ (although you don't have to do that - your code only has to theoretically be correct).

Comment: Oh I misread sorry

Comment: Isn’t the definition of \$h(0)\$ redundant here since it will only be applied to primes?

Comment: @NickKennedy \$h\$ is recursive, \$h(0)\$ is the base case.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious here, but isn't \$h(n)\$ an infinite recursive function right now for most \$n,m\$?  Take the first prime of the first test case for example (\$n=2,m=1\$): \$g(2^2+1)=g(5),m=1\$ will result in \$5\$, so \$h(5\mod 2)=h(1)\$. Then \$n=1,m=1\$ becomes \$g(1^2+1)=g(2),m=1\$ will result in \$1\$, and \$h(1\mod 2)=h(1)\$ again.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The modulus is the argument of \$h\$, not the original \$n\$, so \$h(1) = h(\text{something}\mod 1)+1 = h(0)+1 = 1\$.

Comment: @CommandMaster Ah, of course.. I knew I was missing something obvious here. :/ Mb

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Apparently my original code has used the correct values for \$F_1, F_2\$, just failed for \$F_0\$, so when I "fixed" that it made it wrong.

Comment: I’ve submitted a brute force version, but it feels like I’m missing something here - the Pisano period is useful where m=2 but doesn’t seem to be enough for m>2. @CommandMaster have you got an algorithm that runs efficiently for higher values of m?

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes - you can implement \$g_i(n, k) = \underbrace{f(\cdots(f(n))\cdots)}_{i\text{ times}}\mod k\$ and then \$g_i(n, k) = f(g_{i-1}(n, \pi(k))) \mod k\$

Comment: Thanks - cracked it I think!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
DpÏε"ÐĀiIFn>Åf}s%®.V>"©.V}Åm
```

Times out for the \$m\geq2\$ test cases, but works in theory.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9vc2FiaWX//0Rww4/OtSLDkMSAaUlGbj7DhWZ9cyXCri5WPiLCqS5WfcOFbf//WzIsNywxMSwxMCwxNCw0LDldCjE) or [verify all `m=1` test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGZRgr6SQmJeikGurZA9kPmqbpKBkX5kQ@t@l4HD/ua1KhyccaciMcMuzO9yaVlusemidXpid0qGVemG1h1tz/@v8j46ONtIx1zE01DE00DE00THRsYzVMYzVUYCLm@oYGmNKmoLEoZKWQASUMoXIxgIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
DpÏ          # Only keep the primes of the first (implicit) input-list
   ε         # Map over each prime:
    "..."    #  Define recursive string `h` explained below
         ©   #  Store this string in variable `®` (without popping)
          .V #  Execute it as 05AB1E code, with the current prime as argument
   }Åm       # After the map: Pop and push its median
             # (which is output implicitly as result)

Ð            # Triplicate the current value
 Āi          # Pop one, and if it's NOT 0:
   IF        #  Loop the second input-integer `m` amount of times:
     n>      #   Square the current value, and then increase it by 1
       Åf    #   Pop and push the 0-based Fibonacci number
    }s       #  After the loop: swap so a copy of the triplicated number is at the top
      %      #  Modulo
       ®.V   #  Then do a recursive call to `®`
          >  #  And increase it by 1
             # (implicit else:)
             #  (implicitly use the triplicated 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
²‘ÆḞƊ⁴¡%⁸ßẸ¡‘
ẒƇÇ€Æṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpkcNMw63Pdwx71jXo8YthxaqPmrccXj@w107Di0EynA93DXpWPvh9kdNa4CKdjb@f7hzn/WjhjkKunYKjxrmWh9u5wJLRv7/H22kY65jaKhjaKBjaKJjomMZqwMTMtUxNEYRNwUJQcUtgQgoagqU@G8IAA)

A full program taking the list of integers as the first argument and \$m\$ as the second. Prints the result to STDOUT. The TIO link includes a footer that evaluates the first three examples. Times out where \$m \ge 2\$.

### Alternative approach [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 bytes

```
ẒƇµØ.;S$%ḊɗƬLƊ⁹Ð¡ḊU²‘%ÆḞʋƒ%µ¹Ð¿)ẈÆṁ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrknH2g9tPTxDzzpYRfXhjq6T04@t8TnW9ahx5@EJhxYCBUIPbXrUMEP1cNvDHfNOdR@bpHpo6yGQ3H7Nh7s6gKI7Gx81zPz/cOc@60cNcxR07RQeNcy1Prxcn@vh7i2Hth6d/HDnYoTEwx2LHu6Y/6hxW9jhds3I//@VlJSijXTMdQwNdQwNdAxNdEx0LGN1FAxByo24YFKmOobGWOVNQVJQeUsgAsqaIhQYgxSADAAKGKHogAkYggRMjHXMzGEixthELM3hPFOuaHNDSx0FcyNzIGFsDCJAXBNjmAoToHqwbkMDGNccwQWZD@cYAr0PAA)

A dyadic link taking the list of integers as its left argument and \$m\$ as its right, and returning the result. Works for all of the examples in under two seconds total. Full explanation to follow, but in brief:

1. For a given integer \$n\$:

   1. Generate \$\pi(n)\$, \$\pi(\pi(n))\$, \$\pi(\pi(\pi(n)))\$ … so we
      have \$m\$ levels of this.  Here \$\pi(n)\$ is the Pisano period
      which is the period of the Fibonacci sequence \$\mod n\$.
   2. Reverse these. So for example where \$n = 977\$ and \$m = 5\$, we have a list of `[120, 120, 120, 984, 652]`.
   3. Starting with \$n\$, reduce using each member of the list with the following dyadic function: \$ F((x ^ 2 + 1) \bmod y) \$ where \$F(z)\$ is the zth Fibonacci sequence member.
   4. Take the result of this reduction \$ \bmod n\$
2. If the result is non-zero, repeat the above using the result as the new \$n\$.
3. Count how many steps it takes to get to zero.
4. Repeat for all of the other prime integers, and take the median.

#### Line by line explanation

```
ẒƇµØ.;S$%ḊɗƬLƊ⁹Ð¡ḊU²‘%ÆḞʋƒ%µ¹Ð¿)ẈÆṁ’­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ẒƇ                                    # ‎⁡Keep primes
  µ                            )      # ‎⁢Start a new monadic chain and apply it to each of the primes:
                           µ¹Ð¿       # ‎⁣- Repeat until zero, collecting up intermediate results:
             Ɗ⁹Ð¡                     # ‎⁤  - Do the following the number of times indicated by the link’s right argument, collecting up intermediate results (argument starts as one of the primes):
   Ø.     ɗƬ                          # ‎⁢⁡    - Do the following starting with [0, 1] and with the current value of n as the right argument until no new values are seen (I.e. we’ve reached [0, 1] again):
     ;S$                              # ‎⁢⁢      - Concatenate the sum to the end
        %                             # ‎⁢⁣      - Mod n
         Ḋ                            # ‎⁢⁤      - Remove first value
            L                         # ‎⁣⁡    - Length (which will be Pisano period)
                 Ḋ                    # ‎⁣⁢  - Remove first value
                  U                   # ‎⁣⁣  - Reverse order
                        ʋƒ            # ‎⁣⁤  - Reduce this list using the following, and starting with the current n
                   ²                  # ‎⁤⁡    - Squared
                    ‘                 # ‎⁤⁢    - Increment by 1
                     %                # ‎⁤⁣    - Mod the current Pisano period
                      ÆḞ              # ‎⁤⁤    - Fibonacci number
                          %           # ‎⁢⁡⁡  - Mod n
                                Ẉ     # ‎⁢⁡⁢Lengths
                                 Æṁ   # ‎⁢⁡⁣Median
                                   ’  # ‎⁢⁡⁤Decrement by 1
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 107 bytes

```perl
->\v,\m{v.grep(&is-prime).map(->\n{n&&&?BLOCK(([o] &{(0,1,*+*...*)[$^n**2+1]} xx m)(n)%n)+1}).sort[*div 2]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddDdSsMwFAfw6_UpDqOGJE3D0ll0DCfopYIP0HVQXDvKTFrSDzpCn8SbXuiND7H38G3M3HDsQjh_TiA_OJzz_qGTbTN8yR2grFFwB59Nnfm331t_sWzZUpqWb3RaYpRXfqlzmRIukxLbX2UUQuj-4fnl8QnjqIgBGTxhglGPcs4pidyVojTwRNxD14EkWJErRTzRE14Vuo7oOm8hiPvTyP3cyQoNOAoY3DAQwmZic83A1iy2TwYBYRcitG36PwyP4gxnhxxU-CenBPwFYLdN3ioGrrRJu5KAcUZVshuNN0UNxh7nLEjPwJL0tU7Xv3g8d05bDMOx_wA)

- `.grep(&is-prime)` filters the prime numbers (&is-prime is a built-in
  function)
- `(0, 1, * + * ... *)` constructs the Fibonacci sequence
- `&?BLOCK` is a compile-time variable referring to the current block, so we can recurse with even anonymous functions
- `o` is the function composition operator; `[o]` says "reduce with `o`", so we can compose `m` functions with it
- `[* div 2]` as an array subscript passes the array length to `*` there, effectively getting the middle element without hussle (`div` is doing floor division)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 241 bytes

```r
\(x,m,`~`=sapply,`&`=c,f=`for`,`-`=sum)median(x[x~\(z)2>-!z%%(2:z)]~\(n){while(n){p=n
f(i,1:m,{x=1&1
j=2
while(-((x=x[2]&-x%%p[1])>0:1))j=j+1
p=j&p})
f(i,1:m,n<-`if`((n=(n^2+1)%%p[i])<2,n,{x=0:1
f(l,2:n,x<-x[2]&-x%%p[i+1])
x[2]}))
F=F+1}
F})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJtitswEKV_dQrXkKBpxkskO3UTIv_MJWwXpa29cXBUEydU9SZ7kVJICz1Ue4u9wY42cXYLC2akeV9g9H782p5-r9Sf_a4MPvx9yLjFDep7rdpl09TfUQ-1-oyl0uXXrUYdELHfwKb4Ui0Nt6m9z3gHMgnedoMBl7MOckIM3H1bVXXhLo0yrOQVitkG76wSQ8HWSrIzH3BulU1lPgzsYNCkIodkPBMAa7UeCdao9bA5wtVv5oGuSs25Udx8lCMBzlTlMJdoXDp5SVyjnBm08-BFcjWibOaAIwBbqMVIHNniCOcf__fmZ2GVn0qMUQgUYxQRRjjN0RNekHiS9dQERfgqP3HUhZ_SR-zkWRA6gQsgQP7n6AHhgCjE93GPhK8h0_i6TVgaiyl6sYxphKEbbo3CXhGR_sktxv0aP68u_7oI_5C0u23b1NWO-5nx4ZAUNafJqRNw2-4_cZ-EN-8OWZb66PtoARz_wpVRnDPWT93hrhqX61XUIXkBvWV7U5ldcVts6TnOXeOFRc95VrxLqQoURqfMc7i80ul0Ph8B)

A function taking the vector of integers as its first argument and \$m\$ as its second. Returns an integer.

This uses the same methodology described in [my second Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269010/42248), but uses no built-ins for checking primes or the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language(Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 132 bytes

132 bytes, it can be golfed much more.

```mathematica
g[0,n_]:=n
g[m_,n_]:=g[m-1,Fibonacci[n*n+1]]
h[m_,0]=0
h[m_,n_]:=h[m,g[m,n]~Mod~n]+1
F[l_,m_]:=Median[Map[h[m,#]&,Select[l,PrimeQ]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5Nq8IwEEX3/RXBB6J1hLZaeTxx9aCuiorLYaixBg0kU9G4Ev3rNVU3fmyGwz33wljpdspKp0tZ/xslD9iammotzSps0bjeYgRc0N@Egy3a4sGe@jFkel2xLEuNHHIvJgp2TSOiSfSge9cT@D4wXfNqc2XqxUGGpgDb2FxttGTM5R6b4g@1YamMKh0amB@0VQsiqjuhmJ3c/uSOIuwGPmeHGZ4TEAMQQxApiNEFhH9h/G7T@02@WT8cgfj1JvI6edHp5@CZ1Dc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 252 bytes

```python
from statistics import*
f=lambda n:f(n-1)+f(n-2)if n>1else n
g=lambda m,n:g(m-1,f(n*n+1))if m>0else n
h=lambda m,n:h(m,g(m,n)%n)+1if n>0else 0
F=lambda l,m:median(map(lambda n:h(m,n),filter(lambda n:0not in map(lambda m:n%(m+2),range(n-2))and n!=1,l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7BjoIwEAbgO0/RPZh0ZExoFWNI9OhLGA91aaFJZyClF58ekV13cffQTPr3m@bv76nteDuOLnYkhmSSH5L/HISnvotpnbljMHSrjeDKSd4oyJ9Dg3eCT8qGwQrOmhci5KqRtFE4qTXnCp6QTsU3bJewlYQTRoYVQ67mH79gkZ1fMCBVZGtvWJLp5U@Zdl5E50Oy8TcuuEvCs1hYqnglKdeA0XBj5/ZguBb8cVQYAGDso@ckz/KicYs7LHF/xal69paX09H/8h3u8YCquKJePpR/4XwfHw)